# Surface Integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Im struggling to find an answer to this problem. I know I have to use Guass's Divergence Theorem and I get stuck at calculating the volume.

Let **F**: $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a vector field. Where **F**$(x,y,z)= ( 2x, y, 3 )$ 
and $S$ is the surface of a sphere $x^2+y^2$+$(z-2)^2=8$  that lies above the $xy$ plane and the normal is pointing outwards.

Calculate on S  $$\iint \textbf{F} dS$$

Comment: Thanks I must've missed it. It is =8. I just edited it.

Comment: Can't use Div theorem since the surface isn't closed. Just need to parameterize hemisphere above $xy$ plane and use normal surface integral formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameterization of hemisphere: $r(\theta,\phi) = \langle \sqrt{8} \sin \phi \cos \theta, \sqrt{8} \sin \phi \sin \theta, \sqrt{8} \cos \phi \rangle$ for $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $0 \le \phi \le \pi/2$. This is from spheerical coordinates.

Then $r_\theta \times r_\phi = \langle - \sqrt{8} \sin \phi \sin \theta, \sqrt{8} \sin \phi \cos \theta, 0 \rangle \times \langle \sqrt{8} \cos \phi \cos \theta, \sqrt{8} \cos \phi \sin \theta, -\sqrt{8} \sin \phi \rangle = \langle -8 \cos \theta \sin^2 \phi, -8 \sin \theta \sin^2 \phi, -16 \sin \phi \cos \phi \rangle.$

Looking at $\phi=0$ and the $z$-component, we see that this corresponds to inwards normal, so negate the above. Then,

The surface integral equals
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} F(r(\theta,\phi)) \cdot (r_\theta \times r_\phi) \; d \phi d \theta
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \langle 2 \sqrt{8} \sin \phi \cos \theta, \sqrt{8} \sin \phi \sin \theta, 3 \rangle \cdot (r_\theta \times r_\phi) \; d \phi \, d \theta \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} 16 \sqrt{8} \sin^3 \phi \cos^2 \theta + 8 \sqrt{8} \sin^3\phi \sin^2 \theta + 48 \sin \phi \cos \phi \; d \phi \; d \theta
\end{align*}
From here I think you just have to grind it out. I have to go now, let me know if you have questions/ think i made an error.

Comment: This was my first attempt, but this question is worth around 20 marks alone. Surely it must have more working to it  than this?

Answer (score 0):

From Gauss-Divergence theorem we know that 
$$ \iint \limits_S \mathbf{F} ds=\iiint \limits \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} dV $$
\begin{align*}
\iint \limits_S \mathbf{F} ds & =\iiint \limits \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}\\
& = \iiint 3 dV=3 (\text{Volume of the sphere})\\
& = 3\times \frac{4}{3}\pi (2\sqrt{2})^3=64 \sqrt{2}\ \pi
\end{align*}